# Serial Port Data Received Event accessed from Multiple forms

Tags: c#, forms, serial-port

I'm trying to make a windows form application in Visual Studio in C# and the purpose is to be able to communicate with an Arduino microcontroller. Right now I have 2 forms (Form1 and Form2) and I need to send and receive data from both windows to the microcontroller. I have defined a class SerialComms.cs in which there I start my serialPort and I have been able to send messages from both forms to the Arduino.

The problem is I don't know how to go about to receiving data from the Arduino as soon as the data is received. If I were to create the serialPort from one of the forms i would be able to create a function for DataReceived that will run anytime data is received but I don't know how to do that when I start my serialPort from a class. Any help?

Here is my code for both forms and my serialComms class:

**Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace Test_Comms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connectToArduino();
        }

        void connectToArduino()
        {
            try { SerialComms.SerialPort.Close(); }
            catch { }
            getAvailablePorts();
            for (int i = 0; i < COMcomboBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                string inputMsg = "None";
                string commport = COMcomboBox.GetItemText(COMcomboBox.Items[i]);
                //Wait for Arduino message sent
                //If not receieved go to next port
                SerialComms.SerialPort.PortName = commport;
                SerialComms.SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                SerialComms.SerialPort.Open();
                try { SerialComms.SerialPort.Open(); }
                catch { }

                int counter1 = 0;
                while (counter1 < 100)
                {
                    inputMsg = SerialComms.SerialPort.ReadLine();
                    try { inputMsg = SerialComms.SerialPort.ReadLine(); }
                    catch { }
                    counter1++;
                    if (inputMsg == "Arduino")
                    {
                        counter1 = 1000;
                    }
                }
                if (inputMsg != "Arduino")
                {
                    try { SerialComms.SerialPort.Close(); }
                    catch { }
                }
                else
                { 
                    i = COMcomboBox.Items.Count;
                    SerialComms.SerialPort.WriteLine("Connection Established");
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected";

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        void getAvailablePorts()
        {
            COMcomboBox.Items.Clear();
            String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            COMcomboBox.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialComms.SerialPort.WriteLine("LED ON");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            SerialComms.SerialPort.WriteLine("LED OFF");
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Opens second form
        {
            Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
            settingsForm.ShowDialog();
         }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace Test_Comms
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public static string text = "Test text";
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialComms.SerialPort.WriteLine("LED ON");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialComms.SerialPort.WriteLine("LED OFF");

            button2.Text = text;

         }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**SerialComms.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace Test_Comms
{

    public static class SerialComms
    {
        //public static delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, ReceivedEventArgs e);
        //public static event DataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;

        private static SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();



        public static SerialPort SerialPort
        {

            get { return _serialPort; }
            set { _serialPort = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please note: since the `SerialPort` is `static` it means that it exists only 1 time! if you close it in one form it will not be accessible in the other!

Comment: @PaulF the class is `static` and the property `SerialPort` is `static`... How can there be different instances ?=!

Comment: [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) is modal, that means it will block all input on form1. if you want to use both forms in parallel you need to call `Show` on form2 in the `button3_Click` method

Comment: @MongZhu: you are right - I just hadn't scrolled down far enough to see the button3_Click event

Comment: @MongZhu: the DataReceived event surely cant be connected to both forms - any read of data received will extract the data from the input buffer, so only be available to one form - there needs to be some form of synchronisation for both forms to successfully use the single resource.

Comment: This can not come to a good end, there must be only one subscriber of the event.  If other components need to know what was received as well then just raise your own event.

Comment: Also if OP uses the Show method, which is the correct method to use if both forms are to work in parallel, this will lead to the possibility of clicking button3 creating more instances of Form2.

Comment: ok on the second thought you're right, only one subscriber, otherwise the pull each other the food from the plate.

Comment: If I were to access the Data received from only one form, what would the code look like? I'm a noob to this, been working on C# for the past 2 months alone so not much experience. Thanks in advance

Comment: then I would suggest to handle the `DataReceived` event in the `SerialComms` class. Make a further static event in the `SerialComms` class which can transmit a string. You can fire it everytime you get a new message on the serial port via the `DataReceived` event. The static event can then be hooked to the forms and distribute the received data from the port to any form in your programm

Comment: here is [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) with an example of how to use the event